# apache mod_Jk error log

Tags: apache, tomcat, forwarding, mod-jk

im runing an apache Webserver and a tomcat server.
Im now trying to forward to the tomcat from the apache. Both Servers are online and running and mod_jk is installed.
But i keep getting Errors when i try it:
Bad Gateway

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
Here is the mod_jk error log File, can someone help me?
http://txs.io/o3Pb

The workers.properties looks like this:

```
  workers.tomcat_home= /"Directory of the tomcat"
  # Define 1 real worker using ajp13
  worker.list=worker1
  # Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
  worker.worker1.type=ajp13
  worker.worker1.host=localhost
  worker.worker1.port=***** /*Port of the tomcat*/
```

I hope i delivered all Informations u need to know
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
[Tue Jan 05 02:11:11 2016] [24716:140046289016640] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3591): mod_jk/1.2.41 initialized
```

That means your mod_jk installed and in init state. The problem is with your mod_jk configuration files. you need to configure workers.properties and mod_jk.conf

Try this as workers.properties:

```
# vi /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
worker.list=worker1
# Define Node1
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

for mod_jk.conf:

```
# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf
<IfModule !mod_jk.c>
  LoadModule jk_module "/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"
</IfModule>

JkWorkersFile "/etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties"
JkLogFile "/var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log"
JkLogLevel info

#NameVirtualHost 159.253.xx.xx:80
<VirtualHost 159.253.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName  localhost
    JkMount /manager worker1
    JkMount /manager/* worker1

    JkMount /docs worker1
    JkMount /docs/* worker1

    JkMount /examples worker1
    JkMount /examples/* worker1

    JkMount /host-manager worker1
    JkMount /host-manager/* worker1

    JkMount /servlet/* worker1
    JkMount /*.jsp worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart your httpd

Cheers!!

Comment: let me know if you face any problems